# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: " How can I solve this?

Tags: python, file-not-found

I'm using pycharm and trying to iterate over a Directory that contains two folders with excel sheets inside each one and I'm always receiving this error message. Could you help me please?

```
path = '/Users/Henrique/Desktop/Rota Brasil Geral'

for x in os.listdir(path):
    if not x.startswith("."):
        for y in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, x)):
            if not y.startswith("."):
                file_path = (os.path.join(path, x, y))

                rod_merged = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=[0])
                extract_state = str(rod_merged.iloc[[], [0]])
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: What's the error message? Show us the exception, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just use glob, it's safer. Alternately you could use `os.walk` or `scandir.walk` to iterate through an find files.

```
import glob
path = '/Users/Henrique/Desktop/Rota Brasil Geral'

for file_path in glob.glob(path + '*.*'):
    rod_merged = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=[0])
    extract_state = str(rod_merged.iloc[[], [0]])
```